# How do I keep this scenario to 1 round trip?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a page that is a list of users. The controller's Index function is the action responsible for showing the page of users. The user can select those users and chose to delete them.

I perform the delete action with an ajax request, however then the page's list of users is out of date. So I reload the page because I want to re-use the index action, and all the query string parameters are still there. This means I'm performing two round trips. How do I avoid this?

```
function DeleteUsers()
{
    var selectedUserIds = ;
    $.post("/Account/DeleteUsers",
    { 
        userIds: selectedUserIds
    },
    function (data) {
        if( data.status == "success"){
            location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

Index function:

```
    [AuthorizeActionFilter]
    public ActionResult Index(UserModel model)
    {
        ViewData["PageTitle"] = ServiceSite.Resources.Resources.REGISTERED_USERS;
        ViewBag.MaxUsersPerPage = PAGE_MAX_COUNT;

        if(model  == null)
        {
            model = new UserModel();
        }

        int totalCount = 0;

        //Get users
        model.Users = CADC.GetUsers(AccountController.GetRegionID(), model.CompanyID, out totalCount, 
            model.SortField, model.PageNumber * PAGE_MAX_COUNT, PAGE_MAX_COUNT, model.Ascending, User.Identity.Name);

        model.TotalUserCount = totalCount;

        int totalPages = totalCount / PAGE_MAX_COUNT;
        model.TotalPages = (totalCount % PAGE_MAX_COUNT) == 0 ? totalPages : totalPages + 1;

        return View(model);
    }
```

and the model:

```
public class UserModel
{
   public bool Ascending { get; set; }

    public int PageNumber { get; set; }

    public string SortField { get; set; }

    public int TotalUserCount { get; set; }

    public int TotalPages { get; set; }

    public long CompanyID { get; set; }

    public List<User> Users { get; set; }

    public UserModel()
    {
        this.Ascending = true;
        this.PageNumber = 0;
        this.SortField = "FirstName";
        this.CompanyID = 0;
        this.TotalUserCount = 0;
        this.TotalPages = 0;
    }
```

}

Comment: Do you really need to re-fetch the list after the delete operation?  When the AJAX request reports success, can't you just remove those rows from the HTML via JavaScript?  What's the difference between that and re-fetching the whole list?

Comment: Is this a common practice? The page also has totals on the page, which I could calculate, but the pagination would be confusing. The page has "Showing 1 to 50 of 250". So If I delete 10 devices, I suppose I could update it to "Showing 1 to 40 of 240".

Comment: Another option could be to have the delete operation itself return the updated list, then just re-bind the page elements to that list.

Comment: Can I pass the query string to the Delete Action, and then after performing the delete action, return Index(...)? Or I can put the Index() controller's logic into the delete action, and return the Index View?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something about your design, this shouldn't need to be coupled across actions.  Whatever operation populates the index model can also populate a model to return as JSON after the delete action.

Comment: I could return the updated list, but outside of that list is a section that displays totals and pagination info which would also need to be updated. They are separated so they can't be in the same partial view.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @David's comments.  In the AJAX success block, remove the rows just deleted based on what you requested to delete.

The pagination is indeed more complicated; either adjust it in the same way, or revamp everything to use a proper view model in Javascript with bound elements--see [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org) or other such frameworks.